# What is the best way to rank on google

Tags: seo, google-analytics

What is the best way to quickly reach on google

iam trying many submission but it not working

Answer (score 0):

That's a vast question but as always, be sure you give google google a reason to make your site rank higher than other. it will dot it because :

1. your webpage speak clearly about the keywork you targeted
2. your webpage use multiples words in the subject it talk about and not only the keyword (semantical approach)
3. Your website receive multiple and pertinent backlink from other website talking about the same subject